# View all files changed since branch (TFS)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Using VS2013 and/or VisualStudio.com, is it possible after creating a branch ("Main" branched to "Dev001") to view a list of all the files that differ between "Main" and "Dev001"?
For example, I'd like to see all the files that have been amended/created within the current branch, since it was branched.

The closest I have got is right-clicking the branch, selecting *View History*, then clicking each changeset to view the files in the *Changeset Details* panel, however, there are many changesets in there which is taking a long time.

Please note I am not using Git.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just right click on your Main branch in **Source Control Explorer** an select **Compare...**. From there you can specify the path to your branch and the versions you would like to compare.

Comment: Same applies to Team Explorer Everywhere for Eclipse